# Subsequences of primes and arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

By the [Green-Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) theorem it is known that "the sequence of prime numbers contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions".

Is this also true (or expected to be):

> Every subsequence of the sequence of prime numbers contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.

Comment: No: a very sparse subsequence can easily be constructed to avoid three-term APs.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen: start with $s_1 = 2$ and then choose $s_i$ to be the least prime strictly greater than $2s_{i-1}$.

Comment: Green-Tao is true for subset of integers of non-zero density, and is extended to the primes (of density $\frac{1}{\log N} \to 0$) from a pseudo-random argument.